# Jquery- How to handle event as a parameter on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event on which my action to navigate to a certain url and then show/hide a button is associated. I'm using this:

ViewManager.js

```
$("#btn").on("click", function(event){
    window.location.href= '#test.html';
 }
```

and after i navigate to that page, I have a button that i need to show hide depending on the target.id.( in this case being `btn`). If the `btn` is the target id, i hide the button else i show the button, something like below:

account.js

```
if (event.target.id == 'btn'){
        $('#submit-account-detail').css('display', 'none');
        else {
       $('#submit-account-detail').css('display', 'block');
        }
```

Now the issue is, chrome handles the global event perfectly, but firefox throws error:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
```

I passed event as a parameter before i navigating to a different url. As firefox does not handle events globally it throws error. I tried looking up for sources and they have suggested to pass event as parameter on the click event(already done). but after page navigation, how can make the event visible?

EDIT-------------------

I did something like this in the ViewManager.js script: `$("#btn").on("click", function(event){
       targetId = window.event;
        window.location.href= '#test.html';
     }`

and then i tested the condition in the account.js script:

```
if (targetId && targetId === 'btn'){
            $('#submit-account-detail').css('display', 'none');}
```

it works fine when it has a targetId defined, but throws an `ReferenceError: targetId is not defined` when it the `targetId != 'btn'`... Im a declaring the var in a wrong way??

Comment: Where is your global `event` declared? What you've shown us is a function parameter, which is *local to that function*. It can by no means be available to code in a different script file.

Comment: how and where can i declare one? would this be the way: window.event =''??

Comment: Are you navigating to a different _page_ or to an element/anchor in the current page? If it's a different page you can't do this via a JS variable because even global variables are only "alive" within the current page. If it's navigation within the current page why can't you do your button show/hide within the original click handler?

Comment: im actually navigating from a overlay message that has a button, on click of which i navigate to the above mentioned page..i wont be able to do a show/hide in the original click handler because that button is unavailable on that page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have older event object in new page after a page navigation. Nevertheless, you can pass information about last event in get request or by setting cookie.

Here, what it seems is that you are just changing the hash of the location. The correct way to do this is `window.location.hash = "#something"`. In this case your page does not actually reload. That means that if you set an global variable, you can access it from some other function.

There are more then one ways to define a global variable.

1. write `var varname` outside any function, and set `varname` anywhere with any value you want.
2. Set `window.varname` anywhere with any value.

You can use this variable by simply using `varname` unless you have another local variable with the same name.

I your case, try setting `window.event = event` in your event handler.

Comment: i tried it and it works for the true condition, however how can i handle the event globally to pass all the conditions?? EDIT above..Thanks!!!

Comment: What other conditions? Ideally, you shouldn't be declaring event as global variable, but if you have to do that, my suggestion would be use some other name like `myevent` or something and use that explicitly whenever you want to use that event data.

Comment: Or you can just store `event.target.id` in a global variable.

Comment: other conditions, when the target id is not coming from an overlay, but on click of some other button, in that case the event target fails..as im declaring the window.event in the event handler function.

Comment: where can i possibly declare the event.target.id in my script?? Thanks

Comment: Oh that way. Declare window.targetId or something in your event handler. Then check if targetId Is defined and is set to 'btn'

Comment: You can do that by `if (targetId && targetId === 'btn')`

Comment: almost did that..and it worked, except it threw an error again on the page where the targetId was not set to 'btn', I've shown in the EDIT above..did i set the var wrong??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62516/discussion-between-nisargjhaveri-and-user1234).